# Does the line integral over a union of curves that fill the square $[0,1]^2$ converge to the area integral over the same square?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

The expression $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x, nx - k) dx$$ is a line integral of $f$ over the union of the line segments joining the points $(k/n, 0)$ and $((k+1)/n, 1)$. Assume that $f$ is nice, let's say continuous. Does this expression converge to $$\iint_{[0,1]^2} f\, dA$$ as $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a note that if $f$ is not continuous, you can modify $f$ on a set of measure 0. Set $f(x,nx-k)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $n,k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$. The set $\{(x,y): y=nx-k\}$ is just a countable union of lines, which has measure 0 with respect to 2D lebesgue measure.

On the other hand, it should be true if $f$ is continuous, without the $1/n$ factor. Write out the integral as a Riemann sum. Break it into $f$ positive and negative parts. Since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, it will achieve a min/max, hence you can pass the limit between your two sums. That'll give you a limit of a double sum over a fixed partition in $y$, which will converge to the area integral.

Comment: Let me check I got this right: If $f$ is continuous, then it is integrable and any Riemann sum for it converges to the integral.

By the mean value theorem, $\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x, nx-k) dx = f(x_k, y_k) \times 1/n$ with $x_k \in [k/n, (k+1)/n]$ and $y_k = n x_k - k$. So the expression in OP is $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x_k, y_k) \Delta x \Delta y$, where we are summing over the rectangles $R_k$ joining the points $(k/n, 0),\, ((k+1)/n, 0),\, ((k+1)/n,1),\, (k/n, 1)$, and $(x_k, y_k) \in R_k$, $\operatorname{area}(R_k) = \Delta x \Delta y = 1 \times 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

You've made an error there. That $1/n$ factor in front needs to be removed. As you have it, your expression $\to 0.$ Just check with $f\equiv 1.$

Let's start with

$$\int_{[0,1]^2} f\, dA = \int_0^1 \int_0^1 f(x,y)\,dy\, dx = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1 f(k/n,y)\,dy.$$

Now

$$|\int_0^1 f(k/n,y)\,dy - \int_0^1 f(k/n+y/n,y)\,dy\,| \le \sup_{|z-w|\le 1/n} |f(z)-f(w)|,$$

and the term on the right $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ by uniform continuity. Thus

$$\int_{[0,1]^2} f\, dA = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_0^1 f(k/n +y/n,y)\,dy.$$

But that $k$th summand is precisely $n\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x, nx - k)\,dx.$ So we get

$$\int_{[0,1]^2} f\, dA =  \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{k/n}^{(k+1)/n} f(x, nx - k)\,dx.$$